# Solve for Harmonic Function $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the following problem:

$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ for $(x,y)\in\{(x,y) | \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\lt1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in x,y\gt0\}$

$u(r,0) = u(0,r) = 0$ for $r \in (0,1)$,

$u(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) = \sin2\theta + 2\sin4\theta$ for $0 \lt \theta \lt \frac \pi2$

I dont really understand the boundary conditions. Would anyone be able to provide some insights? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that the region is defined as the union of two regions $\cup$ but the boundary conditions only make sense if it were the intersection of the regions $\cap$. Let's assume that the boundary conditions make sense with $\cap$ and then attempt to separate variables in polar coordinates. Trial functions will be $R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ and the Laplacian in polar coordinates is
$$\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\theta^2}=0$$
Substitute our trial function into this expression and simplify to get
$$\frac rR\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)=-\frac1\Theta\frac{d^2\Theta}{d\theta^2}=\lambda$$
The azimuthal equation is
$$\frac{d^2\Theta}{d\theta^2}=-\lambda\Theta$$
Consider: if $\lambda<0$, then
$$\Theta=c_1\cosh(\sqrt{-\lambda}\theta)+c_2\sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}\theta)$$
Applying boundary conditions at $\theta=0$, we find that $c_1=0$ and then at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, $c_2\sinh\left(\sqrt{-\lambda}\frac{\pi}2\right) = 0$, so that doesn't work. If $\lambda=0$, then
$$\Theta=c_1+c_2\theta$$
At $\theta=0$, we get $c_1=0$ and then at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, $c_2\frac{\pi}2=0$, so that doesn't work either. Finally if $\lambda>0$,
$$\Theta=c_1\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta\right)+c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\theta\right)$$
At $\theta=0$, e once again find $c_1=0$, but now at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$ we get
$$c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{\pi}2\right)=0=\sin(n\pi)$$
So $\lambda_n=4n^2$ for positive integers $n$ and $\Theta_n(\theta)=\sin(2n\theta)$. Now the radial equation is
$$r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+r\frac{dR}{dr}-4n^2R=0$$
This is Euler's differential equation and we let $v=e^r$, $r=\ln v$ so that
$$\frac{dR}{dr}=\frac{dR}{dv}\frac{dv}{dr}=\frac1r\frac{dR}{dv}$$
And
$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=-\frac1{r^2}\frac{dR}{dv}+\frac1{r^2}\frac{d^2R}{dv^2}$$
And the radial differential equation now reads
$$\frac{d^2R}{dv^2}-4n^2R=0$$
We can solve this to get
$$R=c_3e^{2nv}+c_4e^{-2nv}=c_3r^{2n}+c_4r^{-2n}$$
At $r=0$ we probably would prefer $u$ to remain finite, so $c_4=0$ and
$$u_n(r,\theta)=r^{2n}\sin(2n\theta)$$
So the general solution is
$$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nr^{2n}\sin(2n\theta)$$
Normally there would be some integrals to do at this point to match the boundary conditions at $r=1$, but here we can spot the solution by eye as
$$u(r,\theta)=r^2\sin(2\theta)+2r^4\sin(4\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all,the PDE is supposed to be solved in polar coordiantes instead of cartesian.The solutions of the PDE will be of the form $$X(r)Y(\theta)$$
Where, $$X(r) =\sum_{0} A_rr^l+\frac{B_r}{r^{l+1}}$$ and $$Y(\theta) = \sum_{0}P_l(\theta)$$Coming to the boundary conditions,the u(cos($\theta$),sin($\theta$)) = sin(2$\theta$) + 2sin(4$\theta$) for 0 < $\theta$ < $\pi$/2 means that the at $r=1$ the function equals to sin2$\theta$ + 2sin4$\theta$ for 0 < $\theta$ < $\pi$/2 and the $$u(r,0) = u(0,r) = 0 for r \in (0,1)$$ means that the value of the function is zero for $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} or 0 $$
I hope this was helpful